# Firefox: connection determined in PHP script

Tags: php, apache, firefox

I've set up an Apache Server as localhost in a openSUSE 13.1 64 bit system and I'm currently testing my PHP scripts.

In Konquerer 4.11.5 everything seems fine, but with Firefox 29.0.1 there is a strange phenomenon:
Every 10th time or so the connection fails. Firefox reports: "Connection determined".
The failed connection is listed neither in error_log nor in access_log.

The error must be quite "early". Because my PHP script output.php calls "itself" via

```
header("Location: output.php?changed_url");
```

almost immediately, but the Firefox error is BEFORE output.php is opened for the second time.

I have no idea what to do about this. It's a quite annoying issue.

All answers will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing

```
exit;
```

after the `header()` location change.

So you have an open script, firefox redirecting to the next (itself) and still having one open, ... I think firefox doesn't like this kind of loop ;)

Comment: Thanks! I've added exit; after each header(Location...) call and I think the error is now less frequent. But it still there :(

Comment: @cis btw when you F5 many times fast in a row firefox will cancel some connections, this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any .htaccess file there? Have you tried using firefox from different OS or computer? I bet it's related to your installation of firefox :) (i ain't pro take it as guess)

Comment: Couldn't test that yet. But (as we all do) I try to make my Webpage work for every browser in every OS on every computer...